# The python used by Jupyter and local machine are in different place

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am new to Jupyter, and I found I can not import module on it. I found the answer said because the Python my Jupyter using is different from the Python my local machine using. 
This is the output when I run sys.executable on Jupyter:

```
import sys
sys.executable
'/usr/local/Cellar/jupyterlab/1.2.4/libexec/bin/python3.7'
```

This is the output on my local machine's terminal

```
import sys
>>> sys.executable
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python'
```

I have no idea how to fix it, I want to use Jupyter. Any advice may be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: your jupyter is using the better python version out of the two. I'd say keep using it, and install packages in the environment jupyter notebook is using.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh Thank you, I just find fixed this issue, will post my finding under this question.

Comment: are you on Windows or Mac ?

Comment: @Punit I am using a 2015 Macbook pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by install Anaconda on my machine, and open the Anaconda app, launch Jupyter. At this time the environment is

```
'/Users/saber/opt/anaconda3/bin/python'
```

I think maybe there are 3 versions of Python in my laptop, but I have no idea how to delete them, just keep all of them (hope they do not kill my poor storage 128G).

Reference: [Anaconda tutorial](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/getting-started/#open-nav-mac)
[Install Anaconda on Mac](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/mac-os/)

Comment: Did you create an environment for the project? If the installation size is an issue, you can use miniconda instead.

Comment: @AMC I create a environment, thank you! I am not familiar with Anaconda and miniconda, so I just use Anaconda because 'original' looks better than 'mini' . :D

Comment: miniconda is a smaller version of anaconda with less packages for beginners and you can add whatever you want later

Comment: @Punit _miniconda is a smaller version of anaconda with less packages for beginners_ I agree with the smaller and fewer packages part, not so much with the idea that it's for beginners. Isn't the argument usually the opposite, that beginners are the ones who want all the packages, something that just works out of the box?

Comment: _I think maybe there are 3 versions of Python in my laptop, but I have no idea how to delete them_ It shouldn't that much of an issue if you're now using Anaconda. Just remember not to use the base environment, create a new one for each project!