# In python in jupyter notebooks, unable to import wikipedia API after installing with "pip3 install wikipedia"

Tags: python, api, jupyter, wikipedia

While I was unable to import Wikipedia in jupyter notebook, in command prompt I am able to import Wikipedia. How to successfully import in Jupyter?

Answer (score 2):

Run the following in your notebook and then try your import again.

```py
%pip install Wikipedia
```

That is the current best way to use pip inside your Jupyter notebook environment, see [here](https://hub.packtpub.com/ipython-7-3-releases-with-conda-and-pip-magics-and-python-3-8-compatibility/). That will help you on a per notebook level.

For fixing it so you don't need that `%pip install <package>` in your notebook, you need to sort out which python your Jupyter is using (running `!which python` in your running notebook would help) and make sure that you install your packages to that version or environment. For fixing that you may want to look around at already answered questions, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60318511/8508004), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60311826/8508004), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60510648/8508004), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60351225/8508004). Those examples are just the tip of the iceberg, if you search around.